# Consistency of least absolute deviation estimator (LAD) vs OLS

Tags: least-squares, consistency, least-absolute-deviations

If we know that OLS estimator of beta in linear regression model is unbiased and consistent and we don't have any further assumptions (on errors or anything), will LAD estimator of beta be also consistent?

Comment: Hint: consider the model $E[Y_i]=\mu$ for fixed unknown $\mu.$ The OLS estimator is the mean of a sample but the LAD estimator is its median.

Comment: But I am specifically asking about a linear regression model `y_i = \alpha + \beta*x_i + e_i`. If I know that the OLS estimator of (alpha, beta) is consistent and unbiased, does it imply that my LAD estimator of (alpha, beta) is also consistent?

Comment: The model I posited above *is* linear regression.  Its simplicity helps you understand the issues, which will translate readily to the more complicated models you have in mind.

Comment: @whuber I don't fully understand your first comment. Would you be able to expand a little?

Comment: I don't know. I'm curious myself. My intuition is "no, it does not mean the LAD estimator is consistent" because the LAD estimator does not necessarily have a unique solution. So at a minimum you would need an assumption for the solution being unique.